# Rails: list of pins that a user upvoted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails app with a basic set up to allows users to upvote pins, those pins are ordered from the most upvoted to the less upvoted. What I would like to do now is to render the lists of pins that a user upvoted on his profile.

Here is my config:

**app/controllers/pins_controllers.rb**

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    flash[:notice] =  "Thank you for upvoting! You can upvote a startup only once."
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  else 
    flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvoted this!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  end
end
```

**app/models/pin.rb**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :upvoted_users, through: :votes, source: :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

    end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins    
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin

end
```

**app/models/vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :pin, counter_cache: true
validates_uniqueness_of :pin_id, scope: :user_id

end
```

And my **routes.rb**

```
 resources :pins do
  member do
    post 'upvote'
  end
end
```

Do you have any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: Do you want query to get list of pins voted by user?

Comment: @lcicle yes and then I want the upvoted pins by a user to be display on his profile. Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the pins a user @user upvoted for example by the following:

```
@pins_for_user = [] 
@user.votes.each do |vote| 
  @pins_for_user << vote.pin 
end
```

You can embedd this in your user controller, for example in the show method.
Then you can refer to @pins_for_user in your show view (show.html.erb) and display it by:

```
<% @pins_for_user.each do |pin| %>
  <%= pin.name %> # or any other code to display that special pin
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I updated my code with your solution, but I run to an error: undefined local variable or method `pins_for_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fc357474f10>:0x007fc357474150>

Comment: Where do you run in this error (which class)? Oh sorry, i forgot to add the @ in the view-code. I'll update this.

Comment: When I try to access the user profile at app/views/users/show.html.erb

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to add the @ in the view-code, it should work now, but of course you have to update the <%= pin.name %>-code with the attributes you have for pin and your way to display them.

Comment: Oh How could i didn't noticed that! Thanks irene !